# Paste Windows clipboard with Shift-Insert but not by yanking

Tags: microsoft-windows, yank, kill-ring, clipboard

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Windows 10. I only ever use it in `-nw` (no-window) mode.

I would like Emacs to paste from the Windows clipboard *only* on `Shift-Insert` and not on yank (`Ctrl-y`). I have tried this:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
(setq x-select-enable-primary nil)
```

but this disables pasting from the Windows clipboard on *both* `Shift-Insert` and yank. I want `Shift-Insert` to paste only from the Window clipboard and yank to paste only from the Emacs kill ring.

Here is an example of what I want:

1. Copy the text `hello` to the Windows clipboard.
2. Start emacs.
3. Do a yank (`Ctrl-y`); desired result: nothing is inserted.
4. Do a `Shift-Insert`; desired result: `hello` is inserted.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

By default (at least in Emacs 25), `<S-Insert>` is bound to the same command as `C-y`: they both invoke the `yank` command.

You could try rebinding one of the them to `clipboard-yank` instead.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-Insert>") #'clipboard-yank)
```

Comment: This does not achieve my desired result, namely, that the `yank` buffer is separate from the clipboard buffer. Binding the key as you suggest, I still get the clipboard buffer when I do a `yank`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [simpleclip](https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip). I believe it does exactly what you want, keeping a distinct clipboard to interact with the system, separate from emacs's kill ring.